# grep cisco interfaces without any configuration

Tags: grep, cisco

This is sample of Cisco Switch configuration file. If the interface is not in use, it should be in `shutdown` mode.

**config.txt**

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3 
!
```

Therefore, I would like to grep any interfaces without any configuration and no `shutdown` in it.

**Desired Output**

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3 
!
```

Can I do something like `grep interface.*[0-9] config.txt` where the line before and after it must match `!`

Here are a few of my attempts, but none of them producing the output that I wanted.

```
grep interface.*[0-9] config.txt
grep -C1 interface.*[0-9] config.txt
```

If there is a better solution then `grep`, please let me know.

Comment: Something like `grep -Poz '(?m)^!\Rinterface.*\R(?=!$)' file` (or `grep -Poz '(?m)^!\R\Kinterface.*\R(?=!$)' file`) might help.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Both solution works! You should post it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a GNU `grep` (or `pcregrep` if you have no access to GNU `grep`) solution:

```
grep -Poz '(?m)^!\R\Kinterface.*\R(?=!$)' file
```

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/e7GIIh) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JsEYt2/1).

**Details**

- `-Poz` - `P` enables the PCRE regex engine to handle the regex, `o` forces to output just matching text and `z` enables `grep` to work with patterns matching across line breaks
- `(?m)^!\R\Kinterface.*\R(?=!$)` matches:

  - `(?m)` - a modifier making `^` match start of lines and `$` match end of lines
  - `^` - start of a line
  - `!` - a `!` char
  - `\R` - a line break sequence
  - `\K` - match reset operator that omits all the text matched so far in the current matched text buffer
  - `interface` - a word
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `\R` - a line break sequence
  - `(?=!$)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is a `!` char followed with the end of line.